# Show specific alert, depending on the value of GET in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, get

Im learning PHP, Html and twitter-bootstrap (v2.3.2). I'm trying to display a message depending on the value received by GET.

I have two alerts in different sections of the site and I want depending on the value received by GET display one or the other. not both.

i.e: http:localhost/test.php?load=lannister, should show the message: "A Lannister always pays his debts". however, the url: http:localhost/test.php?load=stark, should show the message: "you know nothing john snow". But I can not figure how to do this, I need a hand, I thought it could be done with an if-else, but I fail to understand how to do it at all. Any ideas?

Heres the code:

```
  <?php session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <!-- Obtain Bootstrap style sheet from CDN (online service) so it doesn't have to be on my machine -->
            <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">    
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                $("#alert_message").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                $(this).remove(); 
                });
                }, 2000);
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                $("#alert_message2").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                $(this).remove(); 
                });
                }, 2000);
            </script>   
</head>
<body>
<?php
        $load = $_GET['load'];
            switch ($load) {
                case "stark":
                    $message="you know nothing john snow";
                    break;
                case "lannister":
                    $message="A Lannister always pays his debts";
                    break;
            }

?>
        <?php
        if ($load==='stark'){
        echo "<div id=\"alert_message\" class=\"alert alert-error\"> 
            <div id=\"alert_placeholder\" align=\"center\" style=\"color:#FFFFFF;font-size: 0.9em;\">".$message."</div>
        </div>";
        } else{
        ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">

      <h1>Bootstrap CDN starter template using boostrapcdn.com</h1>
      <p>Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br> 
      All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

       <?php
        echo "<div id=\"alert_message2\" class=\"alert alert-error\"> 
        <div align=\"center\" style=\"color:#FFFFFF;font-size: 0.85em;\" >".$message."</div>
        </div>";
        }?>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know it's a silly question, but I've been thinking how to do it for hours without any success. Thanks in advance

Comment: Change `$load` to this: `$load = isset($_GET['load']) ? $_GET['load'] : null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in using a switch statement, but as [**@true**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855822/show-specific-alert-depending-on-the-value-of-get-in-php#comment38598707_24855822) stated in his comment, you should check to ensure the variable is set and not empty.

You could do that in long/short hand:

```
// long
if(isset($_GET['load']) && !empty($_GET['load'])) {
    $load = $_GET['load'];
} else {
    $load = null;
}
//short
$load = (isset($_GET['load']) && !empty($_GET['load'])) ? $_GET['load'] : null;
```

Since you set `$load` to `null` if it's not present/empty. You can test like this:

```
if($load == NULL) {
    // message is error because neither stark/lannister selected
} else {
    switch($load) {
        case "stark":
        //do start stuff here
        break;

        case "lannister":
        // do lannister stuff here
        break;
    }
}
```

Now for the final part. This block of code:

```
if ($load==='stark'){
    echo "<div id=\"alert_message\" class=\"alert alert-error\"> 
          <div id=\"alert_placeholder\" align=\"center\" style=\"color:#FFFFFF;font-size: 0.9em;\">".$message."</div>
        </div>";
}
```

Is not needed. (<sup>*The `if` condition is not needed*</sup>) As you already do the conditioning work in the `switch` statement to set the message that will be displayed in the alert box. Meaning you'd just have the echo somewhere in your markup!

```
echo "<div id=\"alert_message\" class=\"alert alert-error\"> 
          <div id=\"alert_placeholder\" align=\"center\" style=\"color:#FFFFFF;font-size: 0.9em;\">".$message."</div>
        </div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up the code a small amount to make life easier on you.

```
<?php if($_GET){
    $load = isset($_GET['load']) ? $_GET['load'] : null;
}

if ($load == "stark") {
    //ECHO
} 
elseif ($load == "lannister") {
    //echo
}
else {
    //default
}
```

Comment: P.S. You could also achieve all of your actions within your case.